# html jquery clickable words and content flowing below

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys i just had a question regarding how to connect my jquery to my html, i know its simplistic but any help would be appreciated, im trying to have each section of my site (3 in total, here the FAQ and Questions section) when you click on faq the content flows below it like an accordian, also how would i go about including the click function on the words and including the content below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <h3 class="remove-bottom " style="margin-top: 300px">FAQ</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="one-third column">
        <h3 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 300px">Questions &amp; Support</h3>
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question, can you please post your code to http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean click to toggle it's function below it like when you click on facebook notification icon at the top, it shows the notification below it as accordian?

Comment: no not lie facebook more in the vain of the snapchat website if you have ever been to it where you click on a tab at the bottom and the information appears from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Here is an example of what i think you are asking for:
http://www.itechroom.com/2010/09/25/simple-jquery-accordion-to-show-news-faq-questions-and-answers/

Comment: im just having issues getting my jquery to match up with my html do i have to code the html or can i target the html elements within the jquery document.

Comment: @user2540758 you probably can - but to get a better understanding of what you have at the moment, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @user2540758 Alternative here would be to provide us your entire page.